# what's the `this` object in gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy, this

with this `build.grade`:

```
task hello{
    doLast{
        println'Hello World!'
    }
}

defaultTasks 'hello'
this.buildDir="binin"
project.buildDir="bout"
ext.abc="test abc"

println "buildDir is: ${this.buildDir}"
println "buildDir is: "+project.buildDir
println "project=${project}, ${project.project}, ${this==project} ${this.equals(project)}"
println "this=${this}, ${this.project}, ${this.project.equals(project)}"
println "this.ext, ${this.ext}, ${this.project.ext}, ${this.ext==this.project.ext}"
```

the output is:

```
buildDir is: /mnt/e/code/hbg/source/_posts/scripts/bout
buildDir is: /mnt/e/code/hbg/source/_posts/scripts/bout
project=root project 'demo', root project 'demo', false, false
this=root project 'demo', root project 'demo', true
this.ext, org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension@3b77c6e3, org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension@3b77c6e3, true
```

it shows that `this` is a Project instance but not the current `project`, however `this.project` is `project` and `project.project` is also`project`.

so what's the `this` object??

when we are writting a build file, aren't we constructing a Project instance? why `this` is not the current constructing instance?

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the script itself, which delegates (almost) everything the the current project. Therefore, when you call a method on this, actually the corresponding method of the project is called. The same holds for accessing properties.

But still `this` is not the same as the project.

Answer (score 2):

An object implementing the `Script` interface. See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/dsl/org.gradle.api.Script.html)

> Generally, a Script object will have a delegate object attached to it.
>   For example, a build script will have a Project instance attached to
>   it, and an initialization script will have a Gradle instance attached
>   to it.

Comment: but when I print the Script specific properties in `project` object, such as `buildscript`, `logger`, it also display the same as in `this`, I'm still confused about their relationship.